# sqlConnection is not defined

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows-forms

Estoy intentando hacer un formula para login, siguiendo varios tutoriales, pero a la hora de poner `Dim con As SqlConnection` me dice que no esta definido. He seguido todo al pie de la letra y no encuentro el error.

Tambien me he percatado de que cuando me sugiere las siguiente parte del cóodigo, nunca sale la opcion de `sqlConection` o `sqlCommand`, ni niguna otra.

Cabe destacar que solo llevo hecho la parte **visual** ya que, apenas intenté hacer la conexión con la **bd sql**, me saltó el error.

No he encontrado solucion en ningun foro ni video.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql


Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Por defecto la casilla de Usuario viene con la palabra Usuario en gris, lo mismo con la casilla de contrasena
        TxtUsuario.Text = "Usuario"
        TxtUsuario.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray

        TxtClave.Text = "Contraseña"
        TxtClave.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
    End Sub

    

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-5AHMNOD4;Initial Catalog=Proyecto;Integrated Security=True")

        Try

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: la dependencia System.Data.SqlClient existe en tu proyecto?

Comment: podrias agregar la descripcion completa del error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución a mi problema, por ser un novato en esto de la programación no me percate que cuando importaba System.Data.Sqlclient no me saltaba nada pero tampoco me decía que no existían en mi proyecto.
La solución fue instalar el NuGet package del mismo nombre "System.Data.Sqlclient"
Para hacer esto se le da click derecho a el formulario o a la solución (Para funcione en todos los formularios es necesario hacerlo así, sino seguirá el mismo problema en los otros formularios) he ir a la opción de nombre " Manage NuGet Packeges"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ6HC.jpg

Luego en el buscador escribir el nombre del paquete "System.Data.Sqlclient"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT9gb.jpg

Descargar e instalar ese paquete permite usar todas las funciones para enlazar Sqlserver con el proyecto. Y eso es todo lo que se debe hacer.
Espero le sirva a alguien que también tenga el mismo problema y no sepa como solucionarlo.
Gracias a los comentarios que me quisieron brindar su ayuda pero no respondí por despistado.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Gracias, tu solución también me funcionó!!!!... extraño los años del vb6, jajajajaja (Lo que me tenía "en crisis" es que usé el mismo código de un programa que hice hace años en una versión anterior a la 2022, que es la que ahora estoy conociendo) Gracias.